# Библиотека Java, предоставляющая готовый интерфейс работы с БД.

Tags: java, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Есть ли библиотеки на Java, которые предоставляют готовый легкий интерфейс работы с БД, где есть возможность создавать, удалять и редактировать таблицы в БД. По возможности еще и упрощенный интерфейс для работы с данными в таблицах. Если кто встречал такие, напишите, пожалуйста.
Т.е. например, мне надо создать таблицу, я вызываю некую функцию, отправляю туда параметры таблицы, а библиотека генерирует SQL-запрос и отправляет его в базу.
Надо для работы с MS SQL Server 2005.

P.S. Работа без сущностей. Все данные и параметры - динамические.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе надо использовать хибернейт, ну и JDBC драйвер для соединения с БД.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, хибернейт работает с таблицами и сущностями. Т.е. когда есть таблица и к ней - сущность. Один объект сущности = одна строка таблицы. Неужели хибернейт еще и создает таблицы, делает запросы к таблицам, для которых не созданы сущности (`@Entity`)? И еще и заносит в некий объект?

Comment: хибернейт тебе позволит использовать таблицу как ява-объект и удобно к нему обращатся, т.е. хибер - это как бы надстройка для удобства над JDBC

Comment: Ага, жалко что вместе с таблицами у меня не будут создаваться сущности (объекты @Entity). Так бы хибернейт подошел. У меня таблицы должны создаваться, а потом использоваться. При том без использования объектов сущностей. Максимум, что более-менее пока походит - это средства `Spring`.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете Spring или имеете возможность/жедание его подключить, то можете взглянуть на его [средства для упрощения работы с JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). Не знаю на счет отдельных методов для создания таблиц, но там есть много функционала для упрощения управления соединениями, параметризации запросов, управления транзакциями... Собственно, таблица вверху указанной страницы демонстрирует.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте легкий ORM - [тыц](http://ormlite.com/)
Меня радует то, что его можно юзать под дроид.

Answer (score 0):

Либо голый JDBC, либо Hibernate и ему подобные фреймворки.